# How to debug "str object is not callable"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
again = True
minimum = 8
errorcount = 0
digitm = 2

while again == True:

  password = input('Enter a Password:')

  passwords = len(password)

  if passwords < minimum:
      errorcount += 1

  numblet = 0
  numbdig = 0
  blank = 0
  numblower = 0
  numbup = 0


  for n in range(0, passwords):
      if password(n).isalpha():
          numblet += 1
      if password(n).isdigit():
          numbdig += 1
      if password(n).isspace():
          blank += 1
      if password(n).islower():
          numblower += 1
      if password(n).isupper():
          numbup += 1
```

I don't get why I get str object is not callable, I'm trying to get the input to be checked if there is at least 1 upper and lower case letter, at least 2 digits, no space, start with a letter.

Comment: `password(n)` should be `password[n]`!

Answer (score 3):

Indexing a string in Python is done using `[]` not `()`.

```
again = True
minimum = 8
errorcount = 0
digitm = 2

while again == True:

  password = input('Enter a Password:')

  passwords = len(password)

  if passwords < minimum:
      errorcount += 1

  numblet = 0
  numbdig = 0
  blank = 0
  numblower = 0
  numbup = 0

  for n in range(0, passwords):
      if password[n].isalpha():
          numblet += 1
      if password[n].isdigit():
          numbdig += 1
      if password[n].isspace():
          blank += 1
      if password[n].islower():
          numblower += 1
      if password[n].isupper():
          numbup += 1
```